# Display categories from a database

Tags: php, mysql, content-management-system

I am currently updating [my site](http://www.xclo.co.uk/mobile/xclo2/). As you can see I currently have a list of catagories (example: Free Offers, Gifts, Accessories).

These catagories will then list to promotions and then link to a single page and each one of my promotion is saved in MySQL under my DBNAME `xclocouk_mobile` and table `mobi` and each one has a `promo_cat` as the field name with a category underneath it.

I know how to connect to this database. What I want to know is how do I get my index page to read and display a list of catagories found under the promo_cat as listed above?

I need them to list the title as shown on my page which is done manually. But I do not want it to display duplicates.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: can you provide structure of your database?

Comment: What do you mean? What fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $q = "SELECT promo_cat FROM mobi";
 $result = mysql_query($q,$connection);
 while($output = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo $output['category'];
 }
```

EDIT:

this will list duplicates if there are duplicates in your database, else it won't.

If you have duplicates in your db, use "select distinct(promo_cat) .. "

Answer (score 0):

You want to use [DISTINCT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html)

```
SELECT DISTINCT(promo_cat) FROM xclocoauk.mobi
```